# Flutter - How can I download an existing PDF in the project to the user's machine?

Tags: flutter, download, flutter-web

How can I download an existing file in my project to the user's device?

In my project, there is a PDF file, which must be downloaded to the user's device. I tried to use url_launcher, but the Flutter Web in deploy did not recognize it.

Comment: Where is the file? In assets?

Comment: The pdf should (probably) be an asset. See [flutter assets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images) for more info. If it shouldn't be an asset please elaborate further.

Comment: @SubairK yes, he is in the assets